# Powershell script to Stop and start windows Service using S.no

Tags: powershell, read-host

I have a listed my Windows Service Names in the Text file and I have added the code to display it by adding the S.no preceding to the Names,

**Listofservices.txt contains**

Print Spooler

Windows Update

Remote Desktop Services

```
Get-Content 'C:\Services\Listofservices.txt' | ForEach-Object  { $i = 1 } { "$i.$_" ; $i++ }
```

**Result**

1. Print Spooler
2. Windows Update
3. Remote Desktop Services

now I would like to stop, start the services by entering only the S.no and I don't want to type the exact full name

```
$userinput = read-host -prompt "Enter the S.no to Stop/Start"
Stop-Service -Name "$userinput" -Force -Confirm
```

say for example if i enter the number 1 the Print Spooler service will be stopped

Comment: Why not use `Out-GridView -PassThru` for this? Is so much simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it following the code you already have, but as stated in comments, this is much simpler to do with [`Out-GridView -PassThru`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.2#example-7-pass-multiple-items-through-out-gridview). Also do note, for these services, the PowerShell process will most likely require to be elevated.

```
$file = Get-Content path\to\file.txt
$file | ForEach-Object  { $i = 1 } { "$i.$_" ; $i++ }
$userinput  = Read-Host "Enter the S.no to Stop/Start"
try {
    $choice = $file[-1 + $userinput]
    if(-not $choice) {
        throw 'Invalid selection..'
    }

    $service = Get-Service $choice
    if('Running' -eq $service.Status) {
        $service.Stop()
        "$($service.Name) has been stopped.."
        return # end the script here
    }

    $service.Start()
    "$($service.Name) has been started.."
}
catch {
    if($_.Exception.InnerException.InnerException.NativeErrorCode -eq 5) {
        return "Process needs to be elevated."
    }
    "An error ocurred: $_"
}
```